# Underbraced under transposed vector/array

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How do i insert an underbraced under a transposed vector that spans over 2 elements in vector?
[image]

So for instance the first two elements under one underbracket with text "node 1", and ect..

the code for the vector:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{D}_{right}^T =   \left[ \begin {array}{cccccccc} \underbrace{0}_\text{node 1}  &   \underbrace{0}_\text{node 1}   &  \underbrace{0}_\text{node 2}   &   \underbrace{0}_\text{node 2}   &      \underbrace{ U_{x}}_\text{node 3}  &   \underbrace{ U_{y}}_\text{node 3}   &   \underbrace{\cos \left(\theta \right) \Delta}_\text{node 4}    &   \underbrace{\sin \left(\theta \right) \Delta}_\text{node 4}   \end {array}
 \right]
\end{equation}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! how you write your vector? please provide small but complete document (called minimal working example) with your vector.

Answer (score 5):

You can do without an `array` here, since you're working with a single vector. Use ties (spaces, `~`) to stretch out the elements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{D}_{\mathrm{right}}^T = 
  \bigl[~
    \underbrace{\mathstrut 0 ~~~ 0}_{\mathclap{\text{node 1}}} ~~ 
    \underbrace{\mathstrut 0 ~~~ 0}_{\mathclap{\text{node 2}}} ~~ 
    \underbrace{\mathstrut U_x ~~~ U_y}_{\text{node 3}} ~~ 
    \underbrace{\cos(\theta)\Delta ~~~ \sin(\theta)\Delta}_{\text{node 4}}
  ~\bigr]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend nested matrices; for the main one, use `array` with `[t]` vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{D}_{\mathrm{right}}^T =
\Bigl[
  \begin{array}[t]{@{\,}cccc@{\,}}
  \underbrace{\mathstrut\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \end{matrix}}_{\text{node 1}} &
  \underbrace{\mathstrut\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \end{matrix}}_{\text{node 2}} &
  \underbrace{\mathstrut\begin{matrix} U_{x} & U_{y}\end{matrix}}_{\text{node 3}} &
  \underbrace{\mathstrut
    \begin{matrix}\cos(\theta)\Delta & \sin(\theta)\Delta\end{matrix}
  }_{\text{node 4}}
  \end{array}
  \Bigr]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A TikZ solution, although I'm not too sure about its usefulness.

What might be advantageous of the Tikz way is the separation of vector elements and the brace markup in the source code. This might be useful when typesetting more complex / longer formulas in the cells.

However, this approach requires way more set-up than the other solutions.

[image: braces with tikz]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{D}_{right}^T =   
    \begin{tikzpicture}  [baseline,
                          underbrace/.style={decorate,thick,decoration={brace,mirror}}]
                          \matrix (eq1) [nodes={% Control for largest depth in vector
                                                % Change argument depth() to "deepest" node in vector
                                            text depth=depth("$U_y$")
                                        },
                                         anchor=base,
                                         matrix of math nodes,
                                         left delimiter=\lbrack,
                                         right delimiter=\rbrack,  
                                         column sep=5mm
                                        ] 
                          { 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & U_x & U_y  & \cos (\theta) \Delta & \sin (\theta) \Delta  \\}; 
                          % Specify braces in the format "column no where brace star/ closing column / description"
                          \foreach \x / \y / \nodedesc in {1/2/{node 1}, 3/4/{node 2}, 5/6/{node 3}, 7/8/{node 4}} 
                            \draw [underbrace] (eq1-1-\x.south west) -- (eq1-1-\y.south east) node [below,midway] {\nodedesc};                        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```